# Sql group by extract all elements of a group in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Suppose I have a table schema in mysql as follows:-

```
ipsrc,ipdst,framelen
```

Now if i do the following :-

```
select max(framelen) from tblname group by ipsrc,ipdst
```

I get max of framelen for each unique ipsrc:ipdst pair.

What if i want all the `framelen` in each `ipsrc:ipdst` pair ???

How do we get that with sql?

Answer (score 1):

Use [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
select group_concat(framelen) 
from tblname 
group by ipsrc, ipdst
```

to list all `framelen` comma seperated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select framelen from tblname group by ipsrc,ipdst,framelen
```